# React shared project throws "Invalid hook call" for Outlet implementation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-app-rewired

I have recently extracted some base react code from one of my projects into a separated shared project:

**react-project package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^16.11.45",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
  "react-app-alias-ex": "^2.1.0",
  "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
  "typescript": "^4.7.4"
},
```

**react-shared package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
  "graphql": "^16.5.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
  "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.0.22",
  "tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.0",
  "typescript": "^4.7.4"
}
```

And inside this shared project I have 2 Outlet implementations:

**react-shared private.outlet.tsx:**

```
export default class PrivateOutlet extends Component {
  public constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render(): RenderResult {
    if (loggedIn) {
      return <Outlet />;
    }
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
}
```

**react-shared public.outlet.tsx:**

```
export default class PublicOutlet extends Component {
  public constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }

  public render(): RenderResult {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      return <Outlet />;
    }
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I use those Outlets on the target project I get the error:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: {...}
    useOutlet hooks.tsx:214
    Outlet components.tsx:110
    {...}
```

But if I put those Outlets directly in the target project and remove the shared projects references to the Outlets, it works perfectly. Does anyone understand why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you pulling your "shared project" from a feed or is it linked locally?

Comment: I'm accessing it through tsconfig paths aliases. I've already solved it (see answer below).

Comment: Seems like the shared libraries should list `react` and `react-dom` as peer dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was duplicate references due to me using a shared project and the `react-app-alias-ex` package. I fixed it by adding the duplicate reference as an alias at `config-overrides.js`:

```
const {aliasWebpack} = require('react-app-alias-ex');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    alias: {
        '@my-shared': path.resolve('../PATH/TO/SHARED/src'),
        'react-router-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-router-dom')
    }
};

module.exports = aliasWebpack(options);
```

There was another very weird problem that was causing this change to not work and I was able to make work by following these steps rigorously:

1. Delete `/node_modules`, `/dist` and `/package-lock.json`.
2. Run `npm install`.
3. Run `npm run react-app-rewired build` (If you are not using `react-app-rewired`, running `npm run react-scripts build` might work but I have not tested it).
4. Run application and test.